# +48v phantom on electric piano?

Tags: audio-recording, setup

I'm putting together a small setup with

- a condenser mic (requiring +48 phantom power)
- a Yamaha electric piano with a 6.3 stereo "headphone" output and MIDI IN+OUT
- Steinberg UR22 MK2 (with 2x XLR/6.3 IN with optional +48 and MIDI IN+OUT)

The safe way I guess would be to only use MIDI on the piano but I'm wondering if it's dangerous to take the output from the 6,3 headphone output of the piano instead (with a 6.3-6.3 or 6.3-XLR cable) and plug it into the Steinberg while +48v is turned on?

Comment: Why wouldn't TRS to TRS work? ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the UR22 manual, (and if it is designed properly) the +48V phantom power is applied to the XLR part of the combo inputs, which implies by exclusion that the 1/4" jacks are phantom power free.

A regular stereo (TRS) to dual mono (TS) cable would be suitable to take piano signal to the UR22 in stereo. Obviously you'll have to juggle sources and inputs a little bit since you have at least three source channels and only two inputs.

A TRS cable can carry either a single channel of balanced audio, or a pair of unbalanced audio channels, but it cannot convert these modes. If you connect a stereo headphone output to a balanced input you will hear some interesting phase cancellation as the receiver attempts to restore what it is assuming is a balanced audio signal.

Also it is good form to remove phantom power before connecting or disconnecting anything that uses it.